# How to speed up a join on close timestamps

Tags: postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database there are two tables that are filled with timestamped measurements taken by different pieces of equipment on different computers, both sampled at ~10Hz and a typical run lasts several days, resulting in fairly sizable data sets.

I would like to join two of these tables based on nearby timestamps as they do not perfectly match and I only require one value from the right table per each row in the left table.

So far, my queries have taken exceedingly long periods to run, as I suspect its trying every row of the one table against every row of the other regardless of if a time match is found.

Is there any way to speed this query up?

```
SELECT 
  ta.timeStampMs,
  ta.v1_in_V,
  tb.channel06
FROM 
  (
  SELECT t1.timeStampMs, t1.v1_in_V FROM rdMBTelemetryReadings AS t1 
  WHERE unitID=(SELECT unitID FROM units WHERE serialNumber='A123')
  AND t1.timeStampMs BETWEEN 1676989254000 AND 1677248454000
  ) AS ta

LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT t2.timeStampMs, t2.channel06 FROM rdTemperatureReadings AS t2 
  WHERE unitID=(SELECT unitID FROM units WHERE serialNumber='A123')
  AND t2.timeStampMs BETWEEN 1676989254000 AND 1677248454000
  ) AS tb
ON tb.timeStampMs BETWEEN ta.timeStampMs AND ta.timeStampMs + 100
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: That will never be fast. Round the timestamps in both tables so you can join with `=`.

Comment: How do you know there will be only one match in the right table within 100 ms (?) of the left? Is the right always later the the left? How can values differ *exactly? Relevant parts of your table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statements)? Indexes? Result of `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`? And, as always, your version of Postgres?

Comment: Generating rounded timestamps in the subqueries and then joining on equal rounded timestamps did the trick!
Thank you for the replies and patience with my poorly formatted question

Answer (score 1):

Per Laurenz's suggestion, rounded timestamps were the answer. This query was quickly resolved

```
SELECT 
  ta.timeStampMs,
  ta.v1_in_V,
  tb.channel06
FROM 
  (
  SELECT t1.timeStampMs, t1.v1_in_V, ROUND(t1.timeStampMs/100) as rndTime FROM rdMBTelemetryReadings AS t1 
  WHERE unitID=(SELECT unitID FROM units WHERE serialNumber='A123')
  AND t1.timeStampMs BETWEEN 1676989254000 AND 1677248454000
  ) AS ta

LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT t2.timeStampMs, t2.channel06, ROUND(t2.timeStampMs/100) as rndTime FROM rdTemperatureReadings AS t2 
  WHERE unitID=(SELECT unitID FROM units WHERE serialNumber='A123')
  AND t2.timeStampMs BETWEEN 1676989254000 AND 1677248454000
  ) AS tb
ON ta.rndTime=tb.rndTime
```